# Ejecutar subprocess.run en una terminal distinta de la que ejecuta el script Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, tkinter, terminal

**Estoy escribiendo un programa en Python3 con una GUI Tkinter.**

---

He incluido una **terminal xterm** en uno de mis frames:

```
Frame2 = Frame(master)
Frame2.place(x=self.anchoVentana,y=2*self.alto/3,width=self.ancho-self.anchoVentana,height=self.alto/4)
wid = Frame2.winfo_id()
proc = subprocess.Popen('xterm -into %d -geometry 500x100 -sb ' % wid,shell=True)
```

---

Deseo poder ejecutar **en esa terminal xterm** sentencias bash sencillas como:

```
subprocess.run(["echo", "Hola Mundo!"])
```

Pero esto ejecuta la sentencia bash en la terminal que está ejecutando el programa, no en la terminal que tengo abierta e incluida en uno de mis frames de la GUI.

---

No encuentro el modo, **¿cómo podría conseguirlo?**

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
#modulos a importar
    import platform
    import subprocess
    import os
    #validamos que el sistema operativo sea windows
    if( platform.system() == 'Windows'):
        #el comando start en windows crea una nueva ventana prompt
        os.system("start \"test\" echo hellow ")
    # validamos que el sistema sea linux
    if( platform.system() == 'Linux'):
        #el comando gnome-terminal ejecuta una nueva termina y se le pasa el command
        subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "--command=echo 'hellow' "])
```

Comment: Por favor edita la respuesta y agrega una explicación de lo que hace el código y por qué o cómo soluciona el problema planteado.

Comment: Creo que el problema que tiene es que lo que quiere ejecutar no lo hace en la terminal xterm que ya tiene incrustada en un Frame de TKinter

Comment: Ay le di rápido porque no tengo pc ni tiempo esta semana pero en efecto deseo ejecutar el script bash en una terminal incrustada como la del editor atom de forma dinámica. Al ser python mi terminal es la xterm.